# iOS zip with gzipDeflate

Tags: iphone, ios5, gzip

I'm using the NSData+compression.h and the Base64Transcoder.h elements to be able to zip and unzip content.

Basically to unzip the server responses.

The unzip method works perfectly

```
+ (NSString *) unzip: (NSString*) stringValue{
    Byte inputData[[stringValue lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [[stringValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] getBytes:inputData];
    size_t inputDataSize = (size_t)[stringValue length];
    size_t outputDataSize = EstimateBas64DecodedDataSize(inputDataSize);
    Byte outputData[outputDataSize];//prepare a Byte[] for the decoded data
    Base64DecodeData(inputData, inputDataSize, outputData, &outputDataSize);
    NSData *theData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:outputData length:outputDataSize];

    //And now we gunzip:
    NSData* result = [theData gzipInflate];//make bigger==gunzip

    NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return temp;
}
```

But when I try to zip a content, using the simetric way, the gzipDeflate fails, and return an empty or nil value.

This is my zip code

```
+ (NSData *) zip:(NSData *) theSourceData {
    // And now we zip:
    NSData *result = [theSourceData gzipDeflate];

    Byte inputData[[result length]];
    [result getBytes:inputData];
    size_t inputDataSize = (size_t)[result length];
    size_t outputDataSize = EstimateBas64DecodedDataSize(inputDataSize);
    char outputData[outputDataSize];//prepare a Byte[] for the decoded data
    Base64EncodeData(inputData, inputDataSize, outputData, &outputDataSize, NO);

    NSData *theData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:outputData length:outputDataSize];

    return theData;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the Base64 encoder.

```
+ (NSString *) zip:(NSData *) theSourceData {

    // And now we zip:
    NSData *result = [theSourceData gzipDeflate];
    NSString *source = [NSString base64StringFromData:result length:[result length]];

    return source;
}
```

We've integrated the base64StringFromData:length: method to solve it.

Thanks,

Ivan